# Cannot ssh to remote hosts on any port other than 22 from macOS using built-in ssh client

Tags: networking, ssh

I recently switched the ssh listen port on my server running Dropbear from 22 to a random one to prevent the system log from being flooded by someone brute-forcing.

Everything is fine and I am able to connect to the server from the wan side using termux(an
Android terminal emulator that you can install packages).

Until when I try using my MacBook to ssh into the server(under the same network with my phone, was previously able to ssh into the server when dropbear was listening on 22). The connection immediately drops and ssh throws this at me:

```
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

The verbose output does not really show anything helpful(and cut really abruptly may I add):

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/my_username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remote.yhaoquan.top port 2123.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/my_username/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
```

Telnetting to port 2123 shows that I actually successfully made the connection to the server:

```
>telnet {hostname} 2123
Trying {host IP address}...
Connected to {hostname}
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-dropbear
|

��]J044��d����curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.aursa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa3chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr3chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctrhmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256nonenoneM�'�Rf
```

When I change the port back to 22 on my server, everything works again.

Does anyone know where the problem might be or what way should I go about diagnosing the problem?
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT 1:**
For those of you who are experiencing the same issue, a ***temporary*** solution would be using `OpenSSH`. The easiest way (that makes this a **drop-in solution**) to do this is by using `Homebrew`:

```sh
brew install openssh
```

This command will change the ssh client you use from `/usr/bin/ssh` to an alias placed at `/usr/local/bin/ssh` points to the `OpenSSH` you just installed using brew, which the symptom doesn't seem to appear on.

This does **not** solve the problem that this post is about. I am still looking for a solution for it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with git on my MacBook `kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe`

Comment: My experience today was that all ssh connections would fail with this kex_exchange error. I installed openssh with homebrew and that ssh implementation succeeded. I don't know what I did today to break the /usr/bin/ssh "builtin" ssh.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah exactly what I did, too. I dis not answer this question because the problem was only mitigated and I still can't figure out why the built-in ssh won't work when reading exactly the same config as openssh one does..

Comment: My google-fu has been unable to overcome this as well.

Comment: It works on my macOS Catalina 10.15.7 w/o installing the ssh from homebrew:
$ssh -V

OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

$which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh

I've tried both ssh -p 22000 user@ip and via changing the config file.

Comment: @fsquirrel I am on 11.2 beta. But searching for "built-in ssh updates for macOS Big Sur" did not give me anything useful. Besides, my setup is not nearly special enough for whatever changes introduced to only affect me. I don't believe this is it.

Comment: Have you tried invoking ssh with these options? `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveCountMax=20 -o ServerAliveInterval=15`

Comment: Same issue, macOS 11.1. Homebrew fixed it for command line ssh, but Mac Mail appears to still be using the original (`/usr/bin/ssh`) to make it's SSH connection.  I can't prove that (yet), but Mail and command line ssh both started failing this morning. So still looking for a "real" fix, since I believe that is necessary to fix Mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue: ssh returns "kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe" without network activity.

In my case the guilty party was AdGuard.

I added the port I use for ssh in the advanced configuration, network.extension.exclude.ports and it works now.
network.extension.exclude.domains may be a better choice for you depending on your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem as well. Didn't know AdGuard take this type of aggressive approaches to make sure you're not requesting ads lol. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue with `/usr/bin/ssh`.

**Background:**

- `ssh` to a named host would fail with `kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe`.
- `ssh` to an IP address would work.
- Installing a new version of SSH (using Homebrew) worked (from the terminal, using `/usr/local/bin/ssh`).
- Mac Mail was still broken (it uses SSH to connect to my IMAP accounts).

I found this post where someone (yesterday) was experiencing the exact same symptoms as me from a piece of Broadcom antivirus software (WSS Agent) which I do not use:

https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=2593&MessageKey=57c16f08-06e4-4c1d-adc7-bd3f51cc4516&CommunityKey=84278e0f-9c57-4f93-8cff-4530b03e3c07&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fbrowse%2Fallrecentposts

That reminded me that Sophos (Antivirus) had recently (maybe yesterday, maybe the day before) installed a "SophosWebNetworkExtentsion".  They posted this video (of how to accept the install) on 2021 Jan 19th (two days ago):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-qWdv1ynMs

**The Fix:**

1. I logged into Sophos, and under "Web Protection" disabled Web Protection.
   [image]
   [image]
2. I needed to reboot for the change to affect SSH.  After rebooting, `usr/bin/ssh` started working again **and** Mac Mail started working again.

**Before the fix:**

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh s0-backend -v
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/eric/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/eric/.ssh/config line 62: Applying options for s0-backend
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to s0-backend port 61917.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
kex_exchange_identification: write: Broken pipe
$
```

**After the fix (successful SSH login):**

```
usr/bin/ssh s0-backend -v
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/eric/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/eric/.ssh/config line 62: Applying options for s0-backend
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to s0-backend port {redacted}.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/eric/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to s0-backend:61917 as '{redacted}'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256: {redacted}
debug1: Host '[s0-backend]:{redacted}' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/eric/.ssh/known_hosts:40
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
...
{redacted}
...
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.4.3
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-62-generic x86_64)
...
{redacted}
...
$
```

Comment: I bet this is my problem too. My laptop runs Sophos but it's managed by IT so I won't be able to turn it off. This does seem to account for the frequent problem description of "all of a sudden it stopped working" -- Sophos updates in the background. Happy that homebrew openssh is working.

Answer (score 0):

Is there your server with port `22` in `.ssh/known_hosts`?

If so, maybe you can remove this line and try to log again with the new port.

Comment: The entries in known_hosts are specific for host&port combinations, therefore this will not change anything

Answer (score -1):

According to your log, built in ssh command loads configuration from `/Users/my_username/.ssh/config`

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/my_username/.ssh/config
```

Check inside this file, there should be some configuration preventing the default client using any other port than 22. Since OpenSSH client doesn't use this configuration file, it has no issue connecting to port 2123.

Here is a similar issue
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/410#issuecomment-207278540

Comment: What makes you think the OpenSSH ssh does not use ~/.ssh/config? It does.

Comment: In the verbose output, you can clearly see that only one role for * is applied to this connection from config at /etc/ssh/ssh_config. So it didn't even matter what I have in `/Users/my_username/.ssh/config`...